# Android: Layout XML: Inserting Space at the End of a Dialog that is Backward-Compatible

Tags: android, xml, dialog, builder, space

I'm building an Android app that requires backward compatibility to API 10.

I've built a series of Help Dialogs for each Activity in the app with the following layout pattern:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Series of TextViews />
        <Space />
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

I found the Space view necessary because the dialog cuts off the last couple lines of the last TextView with the "Done" Button (which is not in the layout file, but was placed there by AlertDialog.Builder).

What can I use in lieu of the Space view that will provide the same functionality OR what can I do with the layout that will render the manual creation of space at the end unnecessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `View`, something like

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="8dp"
      android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

It will show up as an empty space. Experiment a bit with the layout height to get the kind of spacing you need.

You can also take the source code of the space view from the Android SDK and copy it into your own code. It overrides `draw(Canvas)` to do nothing at all, which is less than what `View` does by default, so slightly more efficient.